# In an Object, saved in object repository, is it possible to change the "Selected Locator" so I could change it at run-time?

Tags: parameters, automation, katalon-studio

I'm just new to this application, and I am having a hard time looking for codes since I do not know the exact words/terms to search.

So I created an object only having a value in the "Selected Locator":
[image]

Is it possible to add variables in this field? I would like to apply variables in this section:

```
/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span
```

I am planning to randomise both of `tr[2]` and `td[2]`.

Or another option, if it is possible, overwritting the entire "Selected Locator" field?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Hope following solution can help:

First, update your test object in object repository as following image
[image]

In test script of your test case can handle as below:

```
KeywordLogger log = new KeywordLogger();

// Find test object
def toSpanDate = ObjectRepository.findTestObject("Object Repository/span_Date Follow Up Day");

// Get value of xpath property to replace row number and column number as expectation
def originalXpath = toSpanDate.findPropertyValue('xpath');

// Replace value
def newXpath = originalXpath.replace('pRowNumber', '2');
newXpath = newXpath.replace('pColumnNumber', '2');

// Update xpath property value of test object
toSpanDate = WebUI.modifyObjectProperty(toSpanDate, 'xpath', 'equals', newXpath, true);

// Get new value of xpath property to double check
def currentXpathOfSpan = toSpanDate.findPropertyValue('xpath');
log.logInfo('currentXpathOfSpan: ' + currentXpathOfSpan);
```

Executed result:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

[Here's](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/parameterize-webmobile-test-object-properties.html) a short tutorial on using parametrized test objects in Katalon Studio.

**a)**

However, if you know how to write in the script mode, you can create objects directly in the script:

```
TestObject followUpDay = new TestObject.addProperty("xpath", ConditionType.EQUALS, "/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span")
```

with the following classes imported

```
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ConditionType
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject as TestObject
```

**b)**

Now, let me show you how you can add variables to your objects, using Groovy string interpolation.

This code is equivalent to the code above:

```
String xpathToObject = "/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span"
TestObject followUpDay = new TestObject.addProperty("xpath", ConditionType.EQUALS, xpathToObject)
```

But, if you wish to add variables (for example, for selecting the row and column number) you can use string interpolation to change the `xpathToObject` string:

```
def rowNumber = 2
def colNumber = 2
String xpathToObject = "/tbody/tr[${rowNumber}]/td[${colNumber}]/span"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the `/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span` is a part of the string in the "Selected Locator" that I want to change. I just highlighted that I want to change those 2 into variables. Sorry for the confusion. So how do I change that long string in the "Selected Locator?

Comment: I gave you the example for `/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span` part of the string but it is the same for the longer string. You can use string interpolation to change any part of the string. The part between ${ and } will be substituted with the value of the variable.

Answer (score -1):

By creating a [parametrized web object](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/manage-test-object.html#create-a-test-object).

- open the object from the object repository
- select "Attributes" as the Selection method
- click on "Add" button in the object properties
- set `Name` to `xpathToObject`, `Match condition` to `equals` and `Value` to `..../tbody/${variableA}/${variableB}/span` (Note: I didn't write the full xpath, because it is long and I cannot copy and paste from the screenshot

You can now call this object with the following syntax

```
findTestObject('{your test object}', [('{property}') : '{value of property}'])
```

Or, in your case:

```
findTestObject('span_Date Follow Up Day', [('variableA'):'tr[2]', ('variableB'):'td[2]'])
```

And you can change `variableA` or `variableB` as you see fit and/or use parameters in any part of the xpath string.

Comment: @ Mate Mrše I tried these steps until the setting the `Name` to `xpathToObject`. First I didn't add any variable to the `Value` to test first if this will work the same as using the XPath instead of Attributes (this is an XPath for a day in a calendar per month). It seems using the attribute won't work the same as the XPath set up. I looked again at the original object generated by katalon and checked the attributes, there is a `text` attribute and I was able to randomise it, it was not perfect, since my randomisation was plain `random.nextInt(31)` without checking the current month.